# How to turn on a 12 V buzzer when transistor is OFF in the given circuit using minimal components?

Tags: transistors, buzzer

In the given circuit I need to add alarm circuitry where the 12 V buzzer is ON when the relay/transistor is OFF.

[image]

Please guide me on how to connect the 12 V buzzer with minimal additional components.

Comment: Is it actually a relay with a normally open and a normally closed contact?

Comment: This depends on buzzer voltage and current rating and relay coil resistance, but: Connect buzzer in series with a resistor from ground to Q1-collector. When the transistor is on the buzzer is shorted and is off. When the transistor is off there is a current path 12V-relay coil_resistor-buzzer-ground.  The current needs to be high enough to operate the buzzer and low enough to both not operate the relay and to allow the relay to release. Should be possible.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes it is normally open relay.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Yes that is the problem that I am concerned with that solution. I tried that in simulation only however it didnt turned on the buzzer. May be the voltage was less. I also tried using another transistor like BC548 only to turn on BUZZER with base connected to Q1 collector . I am trying to look if there is any better solutions.

Comment: Do you have a part number of the relay?

Comment: Wire the buzzer through the normally closed contact.

Comment: @Andyaka I cannot connect the 12V buzzer as other side of the relay is 230 AC. I just updated the circuit.

Comment: @David On the relay it is written as 161SED012UH-T.

Comment: @Angom Simulation is good but has its limits. You MUST model real worls components. Q1: What is the buzzer rated current and voltage Q2: What is the relay voltage Q3 What is the relay must-operate current (min and max if available) Q4 What is the relay release current (min). || Without these specs you CANNOT properly simulate. You cannot ask for solutions without doing a realistic part of the work - EITHER simulating ccurately, or designing accurately or implementing an example (or some combination).

Comment: ... eg a 12V relay with a say 40 mA minimum operate current and 20 mA min release current and a 6V buzzer operating on 10 mA WILL be able to be made to work together.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I already have setup the actual components without buzzer. It is working fine. From your inputs I understand that I missed to consider parameters of buzzer and relay properly for the simulation. For Simulation I used the default parameters. I think that is the reason that it didnt work. Now I will try to use actual components and I will update.

Comment: @Angom This appears to be the relay datasheet - pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets2/54/54120_1.pdf || It is rated for 110 VAC and POSSIBLY  230 VAC with resistive load only. A light is probably OK. || Coil current is probably about 30 mA at 12V. || If the buzzer with a series resistor draws >= 5 mA and MAYBE <= 10 mA it should work.|| If not - an extra  transistor and one more resistor WILL work.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I tried using transistor BC548 and 10K resistor to drive the base of the transistor. Now it is working fine. Also I observe that though the relay is rated as 12V as controll voltage of the coil, but it still trigger as 1.5V as well. So I use 10K resistor to reduce the voltage drop across the relay coil.

Comment: @AngomIt's good that it works for you. From your secription it is impossible to know the details of your final circuit. Please update your diagram and description so that others will be able to see what you did when they look at the question years from now.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want the buzzer ON while the lamp is OFF.

To do that, and assuming the relay has a Common and NO and NC, you can swap the NO and common so that the power source is connected to common and then connect the buzzer to the NC and the other side of the power source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz5cr8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The lamp works on 230V AC. Sorry I didn't mentioned  it, I thought that does not matter. So I don't think it will work.

Comment: I just updated the circuit adding the description of the AC supply and also for the lamp.

Comment: It's not that you didn't mention it; you explicitly indicated that 12 volts was on the relay contact circuit until you modified your picture.

Comment: Yes that 12V is the DC controlled voltage, that is the rating of the relay. But the contact circuit has AC.

Answer (score 1):

The MOSFET part number is default one. VCE of Q1 should be lower than VGS min of MOSFET.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSd6nQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I make the circuits using actual components, I use transistor BC548 instead of MOSFET as BC548 is very cheap and also I use R1 as around 10K so as not to drop more voltage across relay coil. Though the relay coil voltage is rated as 12V, but it still trigger at 1.5V as well. So as not to trigger, I decrease the voltage drop across the relay coil below 1V. Now it is working

Answer (score 1):

Just a single transistor and resistor needed, in the blue box:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLWzi6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the relay is on, Q1's collector is low, which switches *off* Q2 and the buzzer. And vice versa.

Answer (score -1):

Just put the buzzer across the transistor.
When transistor is off the buzzer will have plus the relay coil.

Comment: Yes, and current would flow through coil and LED, so relay may stay on even if transistor is off. Not a great idea.